# verificar se itens do objeto está vazio

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Olá, tenho um objeto que recebe parâmetros de um formulário e envio esse objeto para outra página. Nessa página preciso fazer uma validação se ao menos três itens foram preenchidos. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: mostra o código

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode percorrer os valores do objeto usando `for..in` e salvar em um contador. Se o contador for maior que 2, significa que pelo menos 3 valores foram preenchidos. Exemplo:

```js
var obj = {
    "param1": "1",
    "param2": "2",
    "param3": "",
    "param4": "",
    "param5": ""
  },
  cont = 0;

for (propriedade in obj) {
  // retorna true se o valor for diferente de undefined, vazio, null, zero, espaços
  if (obj[propriedade])
    cont++;
}

if (cont > 2)
  alert("Pelo menos 3 preenchidos")
else
  alert("Falta à preencher");
```

Comment: Valeu cara, deu certinho, obrigado...